# Partial controller with different attributes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's suppose I have a controller that has routes to a kind of roles and others routers for other roles. I would like to let the code more clean separating these routes into partial classes. I know that I can do it.

But I would like to know if I can do this way:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[MyLogger]
public partial class TheController{
     // Admin routes
}
```

and

```
[Authorize(Roles = "OtherRole")]
public partial class TheController{
     // Other routes that require auth
}
```

and

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public partial class TheController{
     // public routes
}
```

and the routes inside each partial class only get attributes to that partial class.

Is it possible?

Comment: I assume what you want here is areas - refer  [Organizing an Application using Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas)

Comment: I read the link, but If I understood well, there is no difference between create an different controller. With an Area the url will also change, is it correct?. PS it's a restful service, I don't have views.
My case, I already have all theses routes in production, and am just reorganizing the code to keep easy to change attribute to theses groups of routes, so I don't want to change any url

Comment: You cannot do it by having multiple controllers with the same name as you have shown

Comment: I see :( ... Do you suggest me any other way to do what I want?

Comment: You could create multiple controllers with different names, and then add routes to keep the URLs consistent across the different controllers. I understand your original intention, but (even if it worked as desired) it increases the possibility of making a mistake on security (e.g. if you or a future developer doesn't understand/remember how it works).

Answer (score 1):

In your example there's only one class  TheController with both attributes. The best way is to have two routes and a route constraint not bound to any parameter that allows one or the other based on roles.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but an alternative you have is to add the AuthorizeAttribute to each individual public method that the controller has. It is a bit burdensome, since every method will need an attribute, but it can achieve what you want.

Alternatively, you can create internal controllers/services with the proper attributes, and have your main "TheController" just forward the calls to these.